# Mockito Test With Controller In Spring Boot Does Not Return Results As Returned When Server Is Running

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I'm using Mockito with JUnit, and I wrote a test to validate an integration with a controller. Very briefly, here is my issue,

1. When I add an item to the repository in the test, it is properly preserved, and `.findAll()` returns the appropriate number of entries
2. When I call a controller to do the same, it returns no results

Here is my actual test,

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun getWhenRepositoryHasOneElementThenReturnOneItem() {
        val testName = "getWhenRepositoryHasOneElementThenReturnOneItem"
        logTestStarted(testName)

        if (itemRepository == null) {
            logRepositoryIsNull(testName)
            return
        }

        // given
        itemRepository.deleteAll()
        itemRepository.save(items[0])
        given(itemRepository.findAll()).willReturn(listOf(items[0]))

        // when
        val mockedHttpServletResponse = mockHttpGETServletResponse() ?: return
        logMockedHttpResponse(testName, mockedHttpServletResponse)

        // then
        assertThat(mockedHttpServletResponse.contentLength).isEqualTo(itemRepository.findAll().count())

        logTestEnded(testName)
    }
```

This is how I am initializing and setting up my test class,

```kotlin
@Log4j2
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class ItemControllerTest {

    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
        ItemControllerTest::class.java
    ) as Logger

    private var mvc: MockMvc? = null

    @Mock
    lateinit var itemService: ItemService

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var itemsController: ItemsController

    @Mock
    private val itemRepository: ItemRepository? = null

    private val jsonItems: JacksonTester<List<Item>>? = null

    object ControllerConstants {
        const val CONTROLLER_ROUTE = "/items"
        const val TEST_CLASS_NAME = "ItemControllerTest"
    }

    private val items: List<Item> = List(5) {
        Item(
            itemId = "minim aliqua",
            name = "Excepteur sunt labore dolor",
            description = "sint velit deserunt laborum",
            price = -54939028.11428884,
            cost = -31369367.44365509
        )
        Item(
            itemId = "consectetur deserunt ipsum lab",
            name = "veniam nulla labore eiusmod",
            description = "ea amet sint dolor",
            price = -5493538.6548884,
            cost = -313267.4547509
        )
        Item(
            itemId = "Nemo enim ipsam",
            name = "voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur",
            description = "aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores",
            price = -5734528.115454,
            cost = -3133347.464509
        )
    }

    @BeforeEach
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        logger.info("[${ControllerConstants.TEST_CLASS_NAME}::setUp]: Setup complete")

        JacksonTester.initFields(this, ObjectMapper())
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(itemsController)
            .setControllerAdvice(ItemExceptionHandler())
            .addFilters<StandaloneMockMvcBuilder>(SadaParcelHttpHeaderFilter())
            .build()
        logger.info("[${ControllerConstants.TEST_CLASS_NAME}::setUp::MockMvc::Successful]: mvc: $mvc")
    }

    private fun mockHttpGETServletResponse(): MockHttpServletResponse? = mvc?.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(ControllerConstants.CONTROLLER_ROUTE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    )
        ?.andReturn()
        ?.response
```

My test fails, and it fails because while `itemRepository.findAll().count()` results in a `1` thanks to the following lines,

```kotlin
        itemRepository.deleteAll()
        itemRepository.save(items[0])
```

However, `mockedHttpServletResponse.contentLength` is 0. Debugging the object, I do not see any content returned by my controller. Please see the below screenshot of my `mockedHttpServletResponse` object while stopped in debugging,

[image: mockedHttpServletResponse object content]

Now, my controller looks like this,

```kotlin
@RestController
class ItemsController @Autowired constructor(itemRepository: ItemRepository) {
    private val itemRepository: ItemRepository

    init {
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository
    }

    @GetMapping("/items", produces = ["application/json"])
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    fun index(): MutableIterable<Item?> = itemRepository.findAll()
}
```

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. I don't know where to start debugging the issue, even.

Any pointers, even around where I could have POSSIBLY messed up, some hints, or directions would be highly, highly, appreciated. I just need to someone to tell me where I should spend my time looking into possible sources of errors because I feel really lost at the moment.

Please let me know if there is more information I can provide to assist your understanding of this problem.

## What I Tried

I was initially using `itemService`, and when it returned 0 items, I started wondering if I had set up the `itemService` mock in the wrong way, so in `@BeforeEach`, I tried manually setting the service in `@BeforeEach` like the following,

```kotlin
itemController.itemService = itemService
```

I don't believe what I did above is pretty, or good in any way. Its an ugly way of trying to fix something that should be a better way of doing (I acknowledge all concerns that people say about how horrible this approach was). I realized it and removed it. Why did I do it? I was somehow concerned and confused about `@Autowired` itself in `itemController` - is my assumption right that,

1. If I mock `ItemService` in the test class, does it reflect in the controller's case for the service as well, are both the services the same object? Are they different? I am not sure about how Spring internally handles them
2. I worry the same about `ItemRepository`, is the above `@Autowired` repository in the controller the same repository as in the test instance? Again, I just don't know.

And because I was worried thanks to (2), I wanted to try the below as well,

```kotlin
if (itemRepository != null)
    itemController.itemRepository = itemRepository
```

I wonder if its something related to how I've setup `MockMvc`, somehow me using the `annotations` wrong (`@Mock`, `@InjectMocks`), somehow not using `Mockito` the "right way". I've recently just started doing a hands-on with Kotlin with Spring Boot, so a lot of questions I'm asking myself.

I know my controller works because when I send a request `http://localhost:8080/items`, I get the following,

[image: Dummy data]

This is dummy data I insert into `H2` whenever the application starts.